# Something like rosbag but it keeps a rolling buffer and saves a file only when you want to

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any existing tool that will record a bag file but instead of continuing to record would instead discard any data past some set time threshold (so if the threshold is 1 hour, at any given point it has the data up to one hour before the current time). Ideally this would allow one to call a service to save this data into a proper bagfile which can be then used for deeper investigation.

The usecase in mind is situations where some extraordinary event has happened to a robot (e.g. massive localization failure) and a bag file of data leading up to the event would be useful for fixing whatever bug may have caused the problem. I have thoughts about how something like this could be made but want to check if maybe something already exists.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334926/something-like-rosbag-but-it-keeps-a-rolling-buffer-and-saves-a-file-only-when-you-want-to/) by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2019-10-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For ROS 1, there is [a pull request adding a `rosbag snapshot` command](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1414) that sounds like it does what you'd like. Maybe it will take less time to pick it up than to start from scratch?

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/1414

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jari](https://answers.ros.org/users/14761/jari/) on 2019-10-08**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-09**:
The `snapshot` command is good, but personally I've been eying something like [strands-project/mongodb_store#245](https://github.com/strands-project/mongodb_store/issues/245) (MongoDB with a "capped collection", which would essentially be a "rolling buffer").

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2019-10-12**:
There is also the `--split` and `--max-splits` option for `rosbag record`. I usually set the split to 1m and the max splits to 2 or 3. This has the effect of saving the last 2-3 minutes of topics. Recording to a tmpfs partition removes the disk I/O performance hit. I also found [record_ros](https://github.com/epfl-lasa/record_ros) to programmatically start and stop rosbag recordings. You can modify record_ros to provide more options such as split and max_splits.